# Error handling for invalid email addresses

Tags: email, flow

I am using Flow for a wizard/interview method of creating records. One of the fields is an email address and I am getting errors due to users entering invalid email addresses.

Does anybody know of an easy way to account for this ? I would need it to be a method which could run within Flow, which rules out Apex. Is there a function/command-based solution for this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.  I have a flow w an email address field that miraculously has not failed due to this yet.

You can use regex in input field validation on flows.

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_screen_val.htm

Where it has the regex formula as:

REGEX({!Email_Address},"[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}")

I will take their word for it as I'm lousy at regex.

Note that unlike validation rules, flow input field validation will pass if it evaluates to true, and fail if evaluates to false.

Comment: thank you very much for your input. I had some trouble with the syntax you provided ; but this works : REGEX ( UPPER ( Email_Address ) ,"^[A-Z0-9._%+-/!#$%&'*=?^_`{|}~]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$") .... Thanks again !